# Job returns "Host key verification failed." when I run ssh on gitlab-ci

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I was trying to deploy the master branch via ssh, but after following the steps: https://medium.com/@hfally/a-gitlab-ci-config-to-deploy-to-your-server-via-ssh-43bf3cf93775 got:

[image]

my script:

```
before_script:
  - sudo apt-get update -qq
  - sudo apt-get install -qq git
  # Setup SSH deploy keys
  - 'which ssh-agent || (sudo apt-get install -qq openssh-client )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    
deploy_staging:
  type: deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: serverIp
  script:
    - ssh -t -t user@serverIp "cd var/www/ && git checkout master && git pull origin master && exit"
  only:
    - master
```

Yes, I already generated a private ssh key, saved it in the `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` variable, I went to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and put the public key there, I already entered the server on which Runner is installed and gave `ssh user@serverIp` and entered, but in the pipeline it always generates this error, I even considered putting `ssh-keygen` in the pipeline, but because input is needed, it didn't work

NOTE:

- I changed the real ip for "serverIp" and the user just to illustrate
- I don't speak English, so I used Google Translate, it may be that the text got confused.

Comment: have you tried ```ssh -t -t user@serverIp "cd /var/www/"``` from your computer/PC/laptop?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bssh%5D+Host+key+verification+failed

Comment: "*Host key verification failed.*" is about **host** key, not user key.

Comment: @Kristian I tried ssh -t -t user @ serverIp and entered. The complete command returned the logout, I believe it was due to the "exit". Anyway I tested ssh -t -t user @ serverIp in the pipeline and got the same error: "Host key verification failed"

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend to turn off hostKeyVerification as you want to be sure to which server you are connecting etc.

Instead i would recommend to configure a CI Variable named `KNOWN_HOSTS` containing all your hostnames separated on new lines like

```
host1.com
host2.com
```

Than you can add following script in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` to add the host keys automatically, if the environment variable is set. It uses `ssh-keyscan` to add all the keys to your known hosts file.

```
- echo "Configuring known hosts based on the CI Variable `KNOWN_HOSTS`"
- |
  [[ ! -z "$KNOWN_HOSTS" ]] && echo "$KNOWN_HOSTS" | xargs -n 1 -I '{}' ssh-keyscan '{}' >> $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts || echo "KNOWN_HOSTS not set"
```

Comment: I put in ```deploy_staging:``` in the script before the ssh request and I got: "This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: (<unknown>): did not find expected alphabetic or numeric character while scanning an anchor at line 40 column 33 Learn more"